# Whether Possible to install two java SDK in a mac?

Tags: java, iphone, macos, sdk

Actually i need to install a Java SDK 1.4 but my mac shows Java SDK 16 available. if i install 1.4 what will happen ? whether it is possible to have both ? because of this may be any affect in mac ? please advise me

Thanks,
Maheswaran

Comment: Where do you plan to get Java 1.4 from?

Comment: May be this question should be on: http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this question for Mac machine or iPhone ?

Comment: Hi Thilo, sorry i am not sure but i  need 1.4 for some research purpose. i dont know where to get but i need to download if you know send me a solution and software link

Comment: *"i need 1.4 for some research purpose"*  What research specifically?  If all you need is to compile code compatible for a 1.4 run-time (which is obsolete, BTW), then the 2nd JDK is unnecessary.  All you need for that is a 1.4 rt.jar and the cross-compilation options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes two JDKs can co-exists. Which JDK will be used, will depend on way your application uses java. If its using some env variable (Like JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME) then you need to set at variable to correct path.

There are certain applications like (Applet) which does not use env variable to locate java runtime. Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/java/faq/) link for Java on Mac

Comment: I need to set a bundle of source code that support 1.4 but i am just running java code so not able to set that. i think at the installation it ask path on that time i need to give . am i correct ?

Comment: To rephrase your Q, you want set the source code to support the version 1.4 (May be in ant/maven or eclipse not clear), but what you are doing is simply running the code which is using the default java ? The answer is : Check out your PATH variable which will have location to run Java executable. Now if you want to run the code using java 1.4 then first, check the java version by "java -version" command, if its not 1.4, Download it, install it as per instructions in the link I posted and use it to run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is fine to have both, just make sure to default the right one and add the other as parameter for the programs that need a different SDK. This is generally done by setting JDK_HOME = /directory/of/jdk in the runscripts

Comment: sorry i am not able get correct please explain me if i set JDK_HOME= ? what i set. i am new to java on mac. please help me

Answer (score 1):

Every version of Mac OS X comes with Java out of the box. No download, installation, or setup is necessary to run applications, view Applets, or even build your own Java code from the command line. New Java releases are made easily available through Software Update, and developer packages can be found at the Java Downloads page.

Comment: if i need 1.4 means there is no backward compatibility in mac ?

Comment: "every version of Mac os x comes with java out of the box" --Except Lion!